# Understanding a Git history graph

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

Below is a Git history graph from a random GitHub project I am studying, to learn about Git:

[image]

The graph is from the GitKraken GUI.

The lower circle, heading up, splits into three paths.  One path (rightmost) merges back into the leftmost path, but the middle path continues.

My question: Given the same Git history, could this graph have been drawn differently? Is it only one of several depictions that are possible (and the GUI client in this case chose the above), or could this have been drawn differently?  For example, I put together another one below (I drew it myself - PhotoShop) where I eliminated the leftmost path.

[image]

Comment: Your drawing isn't accurate. The rightmost branch was not merged into the middle branch, for example. It was merged into the left branch, which was then merged into the middle branch.

Comment: @ChrisShain I am aware of that, but isn't it effectively the same?

Comment: In terms of the end result yes. It is an inaccurate temporal representation of what actually happened though.

Comment: @ChrisShain Oh I see, the original graph shows the sequence of events as well.  Thank you!  If you care to post as answer, will accept.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graph is supposed to show a temporal (time-ordered) representation of the events as they occurred, not just the most visually compact representation of each graph. The leftmost branch was created before the three check-ins to the right branch, and that fact would be lost in your proposed representation.

Comment: Note that temporal ordering is not always possible as the granularity of timestamps is just one second, and we can make multiple commits per second using machine operations. In this case something else must choose the ordering (usually, parent/child relationships).

Comment: @torek What do you mean by *"using machine operations"*? Thank you.

Comment: @Sabuncu: write a loop in some programming language that makes new commits. For instance: `for i in $(seq 100); do echo $i >> file; git add $file; git commit -m $i; done`. Depending on your computer's speed, this might make 100 commits in a few seconds, or even in one second. How many commits you get with each time stamp depends on that, but it's very likely you will have multiple different commits with a single time stamp.

Comment: @torek OK, I understand now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

(Background: mathematically, a graph *G* comprises two sets *V* and *E*, where *V* is the vertex set and *E* is the edge set.  Some allow V and/or E to be multisets, but most mathematicians then call the result a multigraph.  In computer science we often call the sets *nodes*; I'm not sure how common this is in other disciplines.  Git's graphs are specifically *directed* graphs, in which the edges go one way, which are typically called *arcs*.  Git's arcs point from child back to parent, instead of the seemingly-more-natural parent-to-child direction, for one simple reason: Git wants to leave the data structures untouched from the time they are created, and Git stores the outgoing arcs with the parent.  Children can be added later, so all outgoing arcs must necessarily point from child to parent.  See [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(graph_theory)) for more notes on graphs.)

> ... could this graph have been drawn differently?

Graphs can *always* be drawn in multiple different ways.  The question is really whether the drawing conveys the appropriate/desired information.

> I put together another one ...

As [Chris Shain noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565247/understanding-a-git-history-graph#comment93996412_53565247), this drawing is for a different graph (or different fragment).

In particular, note that the original drawing has one round dot per line: this round dot represents the commit node.  The one labeled "Merge pull request #1 from alexa/master" is in the original drawing, but your new drawing has *no* dot for the now-missing merge: that node no longer exists!

As a consequence, the subsequent node labeled "Merge pull request #10 from JakeMKelly/add-image" has only *one* outgoing arc, which means it is not a merge—in Git, a merge commit is a commit with at least two parents due to two outgoing arcs.

Does the resulting graph convey the information *you* needed?  If so, it's sufficient.  But it is *different*.

Comment: This is a far better explanation than mine of what's wrong here :-)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation.  The unintended and real benefit of posting my question has been discovering yourself as the expert for Git on SO and having access to your collection of answers.